# Angularjs control break report

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angularjs to show a history of stocks bought and sold date wise.
My data is consists of a unixtimestamp field. I want to club the date together to show a header BAND of the date and show entries of that date below the header.

I currently used the `ng-repeat="x in transactions"` however i am not able to add a custom if condition to check if the date is a new data and inject a header between the rows printed.

Here is how i want the output to be

```
Monday, 12th January 2015

MSFT,BUY,10,1000

YHOO,SELL,50,200

Tuesday, 13th January 2015

MSFT,SELL,40,500
```

Code currently is

```
<div ng-repeat="x in transactions" >
            {{ x.transaction_date *1000| date:'MMM-dd-yyyy'}},                {{x.transaction_type}},                {{x.stock_code | limitTo: 10}},                {{x.units}},                Rs. {{x.balance}}
</div>
```

Comment: nothing is specific ..very unclear quetion

Comment: http://m.tikoo.com/mse/app/
thats the code. I want to print a header row for each unique date.
something like how whatsapp does by clubbing all conversations under a date.

Comment: Create Custom filter to check it out

Answer (score 0):

you can refer with your ng-if to a function with the actual item and the last Date. the function will check if the item has the same date than the last item and save the actual date into an scope variable to check the next one against this.

```
ng-repeat="item in transactions"
....
 <div class="header" ng-if="ctrl.checkForNewDate(item)">
     <!-- Header Content -->
 </div>


in the controller
var vm = this;

vm.lastDate = new Date("2000/01/01");

vm.checkForNewDate = checkForNewDate;

function checkForNewDate(item) {
    var dateItem = new Date(item.timestamp);

    if (dateItem == vm.lastDate) {
        return false;
    } else {
        vm.lastDate = dateItem;
        return true;
    }
```

code as prototype not checked sorry for that ;-)

Comment: thanks a bunch. sorry for my bad explanation. i will try this out right away and let you know. thanks again.